# Trying to install Oracle Virtual Box for Windows 10, seeing "package will be made available later"

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, installation

I am familiar with installing Oracle Virtual Box on Linux. I am trying to download and install on Windows 10. Tutorials claim there should be a link to download for Windows on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads, however, where the link should be, I see this message

> Windows hosts - for technical reasons this package will be made available later

It also contains this message

> Important: the Windows package below is known to be 0 bytes. For technical reasons this package will be made available later.

Is this a temporary issue, or are the tutorials I'm following out of date? How can I download and install Oracle Virtual Box for Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Windows downloads are available for previous releases by visiting [the Old Builds page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_1).